# Entity Framework not included in references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project with EF code-first in C#. I have a data access layer. I am adding Entity Framework from nuget. It looks loaded but is not included in the references. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is your data access layer in a separate project to your main process?

Comment: It is in a separate folder in the same Solution. I'm layered architecture.

Comment: Ok, so solutions contain projects and projects can have folders. I'm trying to establish if your data access layer is a separate project or not.

Comment: None are involved in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these steps?

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add Reference.
2. In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
3. Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.

I hope it is relevant to your issue.

Regards

Comment: I tried it. It seems to have already loaded Nugette. But it does not look at the references.